# Can't find a good docker image for windows version 14393

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, windows-container

I am trying to setup a docker image for an mvc5 website to deploy to my service fabric Windows server 2016 with containers based cluster.

It seems that every image with IIS configured is based on a different windows build than 14393, and when I deploy those to service fabric they fail to start on my windows servers.

Am I missing something here? Does it matter what server the dockerfile runs on? So far is seems impossible to get a simple site up and running in a docker container on my service fabric cluster. I spent over a day with microsoft/windowsservercore and it just won't work, and there seems to be no way to enable failed request tracing on it because attempting to install Web-Server with all submodules fails.

Comment: What is your base image which does not work. Since you run in process isolation you can only run same kernel as SF cluster itself.

Comment: microsoft/iis, microsoft/aspnet are the two I have tried. I have spent all day trying to get failed request tracing working on microsoft/windowsservercore but it seems to be impossible.

Comment: It's possible and I did it before.

Comment: Have you managed to find an image for this windows version for .Net core?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to docker registry, find the image, and navigate to the ***TAGS*** tab, you can find all image versions and the respective build.

For ASPNET MVC, the image [`microsoft/aspnet`](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/tags/) with tag `4.7.1-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1884` is probably the one you need.

For IIS image, the image [microsoft/iis](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/tags/) with tag `windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1944` might be suitable for you, you might have to add the missing packages for your application.

The problem is likely you trying to use the latest image, that won't be compatible. In your docker image, when you create the docker file,

Instead of using `FROM microsoft/aspnet`

you should use `FROM microsoft/aspnet:4.7.1-windowsservercore-10.0.14393.1884`

with the image tag after the name, otherwise you will use the latest version, that is not always compatible and should be avoided